# Adjust the number of classifications in the existing model provided by TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I have tried Denny Britz's code on TensorFlow CNN Text Classification. Currently, the code is fixated on the number of text classifications as provided by the existing model of TensorFlow. For example, the model has 8 types of classifications. But I wish to increase/decrease the number of classifications. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Could you show us the code you're using?

Comment: This is the code: https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf. There are quite a few files, and I am not sure which is needed to be edited for it to work, so I will just provide the link! Thank you.